# R Patchwork - title and subtitle to group multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I have below code which is working fine and shows common title and plot specific title.

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Generate sample data
set.seed(123)
data1 <- data.frame(
  X = rep(c("A xx", "B yy", "C zz"), each = 10),
  Z = rep(c("G"), 10),
  value = c(rnorm(30, mean = 5), rnorm(30, mean = 7), rnorm(30, mean = 9))
)

data2 <- data.frame(
  X = rep(c("A pp", "B qq", "C rr"), each = 10),
  Z = rep(c("H"), 10),
  value = c(rnorm(30, mean = 5), rnorm(30, mean = 7), rnorm(30, mean = 9))
)

# Create the plot
p1 <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = X, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_compare_means(
    method = "t.test",
    method.args = list(p.method = "exact"),  # Add this line to include brackets
    label = "p.signif",
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.3, 0.3))) +
  ggtitle('Plot 1') +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "pt"))

p2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x = X, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_compare_means(
    method = "t.test",
    method.args = list(p.method = "exact"),  # Add this line to include brackets
    label = "p.signif",
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.3, 0.3))) +
  ggtitle('Plot 2') +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "pt"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "pt"))        

       
# Create a common title annotation
common_title <- plot_annotation(title = "Common Title")

# Combine plots using patchwork and add the common title annotation
combined_plot <- (p1 | p2) + common_title

# Display the combined plots with the centered common title
combined_plot <- combined_plot + plot_layout(heights = c(0.1, 1, 0.1))

# Print the plot
print(combined_plot)
```

[image]

If I need to add more plots e.g. another set of P3 and P4 and then add common title between P3 and P4 and then combine above output then it is not working. Any other alternative solution which I can use? I also would like to make common title center align.

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Generate sample data
set.seed(123)
data1 <- data.frame(
  X = rep(c("A xx", "B yy", "C zz"), each = 10),
  Z = rep(c("G"), 10),
  value = c(rnorm(30, mean = 5), rnorm(30, mean = 7), rnorm(30, mean = 9))
)

data2 <- data.frame(
  X = rep(c("A pp", "B qq", "C rr"), each = 10),
  Z = rep(c("H"), 10),
  value = c(rnorm(30, mean = 5), rnorm(30, mean = 7), rnorm(30, mean = 9))
)

data3 <- data.frame(
  X = rep(c("A xx", "B ee", "C ff"), each = 10),
  Z = rep(c("I"), 10),
  value = c(rnorm(30, mean = 5), rnorm(30, mean = 7), rnorm(30, mean = 9))
)

data4 <- data.frame(
  X = rep(c("A xx", "B ee", "C ff"), each = 10),
  Z = rep(c("I"), 10),
  value = c(rnorm(30, mean = 5), rnorm(30, mean = 7), rnorm(30, mean = 9))
)

# Create the plot
p1 <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = X, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_compare_means(
    method = "t.test",
    method.args = list(p.method = "exact"),  # Add this line to include brackets
    label = "p.signif",
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.3, 0.3))) +
  ggtitle('Plot 1') +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "pt"))

p2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x = X, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_compare_means(
    method = "t.test",
    method.args = list(p.method = "exact"),  # Add this line to include brackets
    label = "p.signif",
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.3, 0.3))) +
  ggtitle('Plot 2') +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "pt"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "pt"))        

p3 <- ggplot(data3, aes(x = X, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_compare_means(
    method = "t.test",
    method.args = list(p.method = "exact"),  # Add this line to include brackets
    label = "p.signif",
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.3, 0.3))) +
  ggtitle('Plot 2') +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "pt"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "pt"))        

p4 <- ggplot(data4, aes(x = X, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_compare_means(
    method = "t.test",
    method.args = list(p.method = "exact"),  # Add this line to include brackets
    label = "p.signif",
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.3, 0.3))) +
  ggtitle('Plot 2') +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "pt"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "pt"))        
       
# Create a common title annotation
common_title <- plot_annotation(title = "Common Title")

# Combine plots using patchwork and add the common title annotation
combined_plot_p1_p2 <- (p1 | p2) + common_title

# Display the combined plots with the centered common title
combined_plot_p1_p2 <- combined_plot_p1_p2 + plot_layout(heights = c(0.1, 1, 0.1))

# Combine plots using patchwork and add the common title annotation
combined_plot_p3_p4 <- (p3 | p4) + common_title

# Display the combined plots with the centered common title
combined_plot_p3_p4 <- combined_plot_p3_p4 + plot_layout(heights = c(0.1, 1, 0.1))

combined_plot <- combined_plot_p1_p2 + combined_plot_p3_p4  

# Print the plot
print(combined_plot)
```

Comment: This has been answered before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69970971/plot-annotations-disappear-via-patchwork-in-r